Why can't I access UBoot variables?
When I run fw_printenv, I get:
Cannot read environment, using default
Cannot read default environment from file

However, if I run:
u-boot=> saveenv
Saving Environment to MMC... Writing to MMC(2)... OK

Now, fw_printenv works fine. What is going on here? How do I get Yocto to work at build time?
Edit: Perhaps what happens is that UBoot's initial environment variables are created in memory via C code. This isn't stored anywhere, so once boot, fw_printenv doesn't have access to the environment variables. Running saveenv duplicates the in-memory variables to disk, which causes fw_printenv to work. This could explain what is happening. But I'm still not sure what to do about it. How do I get these variables at compile time?

The second line of the error message gives us some hints:
Cannot read default environment from file

From the help menu, fw_printenv looks for the default environment file in /etc/u-boot-initial-env. This file contains the environment variables if they're not found directly on the disk. fw_setenv will use the default environment file and save any updates onto the disk (the equivalent of saveenv).
If you're using u-boot-imx, unfortunately, the file gets added to the rootfs is /etc/u-boot-imx-initial-env. Add the following to u-boot-imx_%.bbappends:
FILES:${PN}:append = " \
    /etc/u-boot-initial-env \
"

do_install:append:cimon-hmi-image-build() {
    cp -P ${D}/etc/u-boot-imx-initial-env ${D}/etc/u-boot-initial-env
}

